# Adding row dynamically by click on the button of the previous row in mat-table angular8?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular8, mat-table

I want to do add new empty row when a add row button/icon click on the previous row. As of now i am adding new row to the table by click on button which is outside of the table. But i need button/icon attached a column with the row. If i click on the first row add icon, new empty row will add to the table and user can enter the details.

Here i am adding the columns also dynamically. i.e by click on the buttons dynamically adding the columns to the table. And for the same table i required to add rows dynamically as explained previously.I' m unable to do that. And i havent found any solution for this ?

Here is the stackbliz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfro3c

Comment: If I understand you correctly, isn't this just a case of adding a static row to the bottom of the table? Or do you want be able to show buttons on the last dynamically generated row?

Comment: @KurtHamilton, Yes i want to show "add row button/icon" on last dynamically generated row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Material, so I've created a vanilla version in a fork of your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-veunf6

**ts**

```
dynamicRows: number[] = [];

addNew() {
  this.dynamicRows.push(this.dynamicRows.length);
}
```

**html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of dynamicRows; let i = index">
      <td>
        <button *ngIf="i === dynamicRows.length - 1" (click)="addNew()">Add New</button>
      </td>
      <td>{{row}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="dynamicRows.length === 0">
      <td>
        <button (click)="addNew()">Add New</button>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The idea here is that the button is always declared in the html on each row, but only shown if the loop is on the last row.

I'm not sure how you want to handle the initial case where there are no rows, so I've just put a static row in there. You may want to do something better.

Comment: I need same type using material and that to dynamic columns scenario.